# Symfony 2.1 console doesn't display all errors

Tags: php, symfony, console, symfony-2.1

I'm creating a console command in Symfony 2.1.

While developing this I am having issues with errors being swallowed.

Some errors bubble up and display fine others just cause the application to exit without displaying anything.

In the example below getFile is a function but there is no error regarding the missing brackets. The script simply exits.

```
$this->extract($file->getFile->getPathname());
```

I have set error level to E_ALL | E_STRICT and ensured that Display errors in on in the cli version of php.ini.

How do I get PHP to display the errors?

Comment: Just to confirm, your are running in dev mode with debug on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of this, it was a try catch block within my own code swallowing the error.